# I am getting "CREATE MODEL OPTIONS() format parameter is missing" error in BigQuery while creating a model?

Tags: google-bigquery, arima

I am getting this error "CREATE MODEL OPTIONS() format parameter is missing" while trying to create an ARIMA model and it seems to be telling me that I need to define a certain format parameter, but I don't understand which one exactly it is asking me to add.

I am using the following script:

```
CREATE MODEL forecast
OPTIONS (model_type = 'ARIMA_PLUS',
     time_series_timestamp_col='day',
     time_series_data_col='cost',
     auto_arima = TRUE,
     data_frequency = 'AUTO_FREQUENCY',
     decompose_time_series = TRUE) AS
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', date) as day,
  sum(net_cost) as cost
FROM ads_mif.logs_actual_footprint_cost_daily_raw
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: may it is wirth trying [TRANSFORM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#transform) instead of transforming the data in the query statement

Comment: Option `time_series_timestamp_col` requires as **timestamp** column. Can you try converting `day` to `timestamp`?

Comment: unfortunately none of these solutions worked for me

Answer (score 0):

'time_series_timestamp_col' must have a type of Timestamp, Date or DateTime, but instead has STRING type in query statement.

Remove the formatting of the date column.